Scheduled event based on WooCommerce order status change issue
I am trying to get this function to work consistently but am facing issues. I have a WooCommerce site that allows users to order products without paying immediately. Instead, they have 8 hours to pay cash to any in-store partner, who will then mark the order as complete (changing the order status from on-hold to completed). If they don't make the payment within 8 hours, their order should automatically cancel (changing the order status from on-hold to cancelled).
The problem is that this function works intermittently. I added the function using the Code Snippets plugin. Additionally, I am using Memcached and Redis, hosted on cloudways; which I mention in case they are causing the issue. I am a beginner at this.
// Hook into WooCommerce order status change to on-hold
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'schedule_cancel_on_hold_order_event');

function schedule_cancel_on_hold_order_event($order_id) {
    // Schedule the event to run 2 minutes later (for testing purposes)
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cancel_on_hold_order_event', array( 'order_id' => $order_id ) ) ) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 2 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS, 'cancel_on_hold_order_event', array('order_id' => $order_id));
        error_log("Scheduled cancel_on_hold_order_event for order ID: $order_id");
    }
}

// Hook into our custom event
add_action('cancel_on_hold_order_event', 'cancel_on_hold_order');

function cancel_on_hold_order($order_id) {
    // Get the order
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    // Check if the order is still on-hold
    if ($order && $order->get_status() == 'on-hold') {
        // Cancel the order
        $order->update_status('cancelled', __('Order cancelled automatically after 2 minutes on-hold', 'your-text-domain'));
        error_log("Order ID $order_id cancelled automatically.");
    } else {
        error_log("Order ID $order_id was not on-hold or does not exist.");
    }
}

// Clear scheduled event on order status change to something other than on-hold
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'clear_cancel_on_hold_order_event', 10, 4);

function clear_cancel_on_hold_order_event($order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order) {
    if ($old_status === 'on-hold' && $new_status !== 'on-hold') {
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook('cancel_on_hold_order_event', array('order_id' => $order_id));
        error_log("Cleared scheduled event for order ID: $order_id");
    }
}


I offloaded CRON to server by disabling WordPress CRON and adding CRON server side
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);

*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1

I am expecting all orders whose order status is not changed to completed to be automatically cancelled in 2 minutes (for testing purposes). Sometimes orders get cancelled as expected, sometimes not.

I seem to have figured it out, i searched around and found an article that was saying:
"If your cron job involves web requests and you are concerned about caching, you can prevent caching by setting the Cache-Control: no-cache header in your request. For example, you can use curl -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" https://example.com or wget --header="Cache-Control: no-cache" https://example.com to ensure that the fetched data is always fresh and not served from a cache. This is particularly useful for cron jobs that require up-to-date information."
and so i did that, i changed my cron from:
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1

to:
wget --header="Cache-Control: no-cache" https://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron

also made sure to add the www.
thanks to one commenter who advised me to add try/catch to my code aswell as testing edges as well. Hope someone who has similar troubles finds this helpful
